# Jquery POST not working with input type checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I have build an subscription form which is working fine in php, I have now applied jquery to it to avoid page refresh.

HTML form

```
<input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="offer" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="true">
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newsletter']) && isset($_POST['newsletter'])==true){
    $newsletter = true;
} else {
    $newsletter = false;
}

if(isset($_POST['offer']) && isset($_POST['offer'])==true){
    $offer = true;
} else {
    $offer = false;
}

echo 'type1='.$newsletter;    
echo 'type2='.$offer;

$query = "UPDATE $table SET type1='$newsletter', type2='$offer' WHERE id=$id"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
```

jQuery

```
    var newsletter = false;
    var offer = false;
    var newsletterval = $("input[name='newsletter']").is(':checked');
    var offerval = $("input[name='offer']").is(':checked');

    if(newsletterval){
        newsletter=true;
    };

    if(offerval){
        offer=true;
    };

    $.post('../../subscribe.php', {newsletter:newsletter, offer:offer}, function(data){
        alert(data);            
    });
```

When usig php its working fine I can change subscription type, but jquery not working here it doesent change anything and I get alert from post data as `type1=1type2=1` no matter what checkbox I check or uncheck.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this with jquery.

Thanks

Comment: you are checking only if the variable is set with `isset($_POST['offer'])==true`. do `$_POST['offer'] == 1`

Comment: how to check if `isset($_POST['offer'])` has value as `true` or `false`

Comment: if(isset($_POST['newsletter']) && $_POST['newsletter']==true)

Comment: @chepe263 I tried that but it it didnt work.

Comment: what if instead of sending true from jquery send a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying something like this:

```
if(newsletterval){
    // use the string representation 'true' rather than a boolean value
    newsletter='true';
};

if(offerval){
    // use the string representation 'true' rather than a boolean value
    offer='true';
};

$.post('../../subscribe.php', {newsletter:newsletter, offer:offer}, function(data){
    alert(data);            
});
```

php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['newsletter']) 
  // Check the value of `$POST['newsletter']` rather than using isset() twice
  && $_POST['newsletter'] === 'true'){
    $newsletter = true;
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP transfers requests as strings therefore Javascripts `true` != PHP's `true`  you need to use a string in PHP `'true'` or `'false'`

As PHP will equate a string of any value to true your current code is looking for a boolean `true` which it will always find and so you will always execute the truthy parts of your if blocks and never the `else` blocks